# How to convert a country name to country code in apex?

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a Natinality picklist field in Account object where I am storing Country names. When I am receiving the nationality name of an account record, I need to convert it to corresponding country code

For eg: Need to convert United Arab Emirates to UAE

How can I implement it via apex?
Please help me on this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange! May I ask what you intend to use the country code for? Do you need it in reports, or in some other piece of code or configuration? In some instances you could just store the country code as the API values for the picklist (and keep Country names as the picklist Labels). Which means you wouldn't have to do any coding.

Comment: I need to convert this country name to country code and need to send that to an external endpoint. In 'Nationality' picklist, I am using same country name as label and api name. Now I can't modify it. Because we are using that api names in some other code. Without changing the existing system, how can we implemet it via apex code?

Comment: It sounds like you have some experience with apex? Did you try anything yet? If so, please share (update your question) and we can help you with whatever you're stuck at. Did you e.g. think of where you want to store the mapping? (in an object, in configuration, or hardcode it in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a create custom metadata, which would contain the country codes for corresponding Country names.

So when you receive a country name, you can query that specific Country in the custom metadata to get it's country code. And then, you can use that value to send it to external endpoint.

Refer the below links related to custom metadata:

- **Custom metadata method:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm
- **Create and Manage Custom Metadata Types** **:**https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_create

**Sample Code below:**

```apex
public static map<Account, String> returnMapOfCountryCodes(List<Account> lstNewAccounts){
    map<String,String> mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode = new map<String, String>();   
    map<Account,String> mapOfCountryCodeToAccount = new map<String, Account>(); 

    // retrieve metadata values to get Country code of the respective country names 
    Map<String, CountryNameToCodeMetadta__mdt> countryName = CountryNameToCodeMetadta__mdt.getAll();
    for(CountryNameToCodeMetadta__mdt country : countryName.values()){
        mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.put(country.countryName__c, country.countryCode__c);
    }

    for(Account acc : lstNewAccounts){
        // map of Converted Country Code with respective Account
        mapOfCountryCodeToAccount.put(acc,mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(acc.Nationality__c));
        // use the above map to proceed with further logic containing the converted country code for their respective Country names
    }
    return mapOfCountryCodeToAccount;
}
```